# Can't access TabBarController from ImageView

Tags: ios

I have an app that has a navigation controller in a tabbar controller. The root for the navigation controller is a table view controller. The table view has a segue to an image view. I want to update the badge value on a tab from the image view controller. From the tabbar controller, this works fine:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
viewController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = @"x";
```

But when I put the same code into the imageview controller, it doesn't work. When I check the value of 'viewController' after it executes, the value is nil. Same for self.tabBarController. For some reason the image view controller can't see its tabbarcontroller.

Comment: What kind of segue are you using to go from the table view controller to the image view controller?

Comment: Its a push from a table cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so there are many ways to do this but the best way would be subcscribe to an NSNotification and then from your image view or wherever, make that notification so it would look something like.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:objectToListen
    selector:@selector(methodToRun:)
    name:@"NotificationName"
    object:nil];
```

And then in you deeper items such as the imageview or whatever you post it like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NotificationName" object:nil userInfo:dictionaryWithValuesForMethodToUse to use];
```

And then you get the information from the userInfo like so in you method that changes the badge value

```
- (void)methodToRun:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [notification userInfo];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll give a try. But I also would like to understand why I can't see the tabbarcontroller.viewcontrollers array directly from the image view.

Comment: There is no handle from the uiimageview to the tab bar controller. You would need to give the uiimageview a delegate.

Comment: This worked well for doing the update. I had considered using a protocol, but I don't understand how to set the delegate property in the class that implements the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the tabBarController with self.navigationController.tabBarController. So your code needs to be:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [self.navigationController.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
viewController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = @"x";
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the image view controller. If I put a breakpoint after it executes, viewcontroller is 0x000000000

Comment: I made a test app that had the structure you reported, and it worked fine for me. If you log self.navigationController and self.navigationController.tabBarController from the image view controller, what do those give you?

Comment: In viewDidLoad I put:
NSLog(@"navigation controller: %@ tabbarcontroller: %@",self.navigationController,self.navigationController.tabBarController);
Log output: 
navigation controller: (null) tabbarcontroller: (null)
When I put the same line in the tableview's viewDidLoad:
navigation controller: <UINavigationController: 0x6ea4e00> tabbarcontroller: <UITabBarController: 0x6ea5900>

Comment: @Bob Are you sure you're doing a push from your table view cell? If you are, the controller has to have a non-null navigationController property.

Comment: Actual controller layout is tabbar -> navcontroller -> tableview -> tableview -> imageview

Comment: Well, I don't know what to tell you. Without seeing your app, I can't tell what's wrong -- there must be something wrong in the set up, because this should work. Actually, I tested my test app again, and you don't even need the navigationController in the statement, self.tabBarController got me from my pushed last view back to the tabBarController.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I am just learning so probably doing something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @Bob, one more question. You called your controller an image view controller -- what do you mean by that? What class is that?

Comment: Its just a UIViewController with an image view in it (and a scroll view)